# Grunt build opens grunt.js in text editor

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

Whenever I run `grunt build --platforms=win` a dialog box appears and asks whether I want to run this file. When I click `Yes` all that happens is Notepad++ opens `grunt.js`.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

*From Grunt [Docs](http://gruntjs.com/frequently-asked-questions):*

If you're in the same directory as the Gruntfile, Windows tries to execute that file when you type grunt. So you need to type `grunt.cmd` instead.

An alternative would be to use the `DOSKEY` command to create a Grunt macro, following these directions. That would allow you to use grunt instead of `grunt.cmd`.

This is the DOSKEY command you'd use:

```
DOSKEY grunt=grunt.cmd $*
```

Comment: When using `grunt.cmd`, it won't find my Gruntfile, even if using an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

Grunt looks for a file called `Gruntfile.js` in the current directory. You've named the file `grunt.js` and windows is trying to execute it.

You should install grunt as a global resource using `npm install -g grunt grunt-cli`

I've had problems where nodejs does not add the npm global folder to the system path. If you've installed grunt globally and running `C:>grunt` doesn't work. You need to add the following path:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm;
```

Right click on "my computer" and select "Advanced system settings". Click the "Environment variables" button and the above to the "PATH" variable.

You will need to restart and DOS shells to see the change work.